# Arraylist problems

Tags: c#, class, arraylist

So I am trying to use a couple of ArrayLists for a project of mine, and I went to the msdn webpage looking for the synthax. Yet after applying it, the error list throws 18 errors, of which 16 are about "WindowsFormsApplication7.clsAL' does not implement interface member 'System.ICloneable.Clone()" or so, and 2 of them are about "The type or namespace name 'ComVisibleAttribute' or 'ComVisibleAttributeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"  . This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    [SerializableAttribute]

    class clsAL : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable
    {


   public ArrayList dir = new ArrayList();
      public ArrayList time = new ArrayList();
    }



    }
//
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the end result of what you are trying todo, all of those interfaces are not needed just to use the ArrayList

Comment: Pretty please, don't use `ArrayList`, use the generic `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You probably watched [ArrayList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx):

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, 
      IEnumerable, ICloneable
```

So, obviously you did two things in your code:

1. used variables `dir` and `time` of type `ArrayList` (you need only this)
2. tried to reimplement the `ArrayList` (absolutely different task, you don't need this to use `ArrayList`), having added all those interfaces into the class declaration.

To use `ArrayList` you don't need your class to implement intefaces (and/or use attributes), implemented (used) by `Arrayist`. So just remove them from your class declaration:

```
//all attributes removed
class clsAL //all interfaces removed
{
    public ArrayList dir = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList time = new ArrayList();

}
```

If your class must implement some interface, it should contain the actual implementation (explicit or implicit). Please, read [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx).

```
interface IFoo
{
    void FooMethod();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo() { }

    public void FooMethod()
    {
        //actual IFoo implementation by Foo
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good catch, this is not the first question I have seen like this, I was wondering where they were getting all of the extraneous stuff at.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I'd say you're missing something!

You are implementing a bunch of interfaces, but not actually overriding (or even specifying) any of the things those interfaces expect. Kind of defeats the whole purpose of implementing the interface...